# Books for learning non parametric Bayesian model

Tags: self-study, bayesian, references, nonparametric-bayes

Having studied parametric Bayesian statistics during the two last years, I plan to begin to self-study non parametric Bayesian model during this summer and look for recommendations. I would like the book(s) to cover both the theoritical aspects and the practical ones (with implementation, examples of models ...) Thanks for your recommendations.

Comment: I haven't read it yet so I won't formally answer but you can read Gaussian Processes for Machine Learning [here](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Part V of *[Bayesian Data Analysis](http://www.crcpress.com/product/isbn/9781439840955)* is on non-linear and non-parametric methods, which as I recall has chapters on each of basis function methods, Gaussian processes, and Dirichlet processes. (Don't have my copy handy.)

*[Gaussian Processes for Machine Learning](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/)* is comprehensive, covering both theory and implementation, and is freely available online.

If you're interested in resources outside of full books, the [tutorials](https://github.com/fonnesbeck/Bios366) by Chris Fonnesbeck on Dirichlet and Gaussian processes were very valuable to me. (Sections 5.1 and 5.2 in the "Notebooks" folder.)

Last, the Machine Learning Summer School 2009 [lectures](http://videolectures.net/mlss09uk_cambridge/) include two talks on non-parametric Bayesian methods. I haven't seen those two yet, but every other lecture I've watched in the series gave a top-notch introduction to its topic.

Comment: Part V of BDA3 is titled "Nonlinear and Nonparametric Models".

Answer (score 1):

A fantastic reference is [*Fundamentals of Nonparametric Bayesian Inference* by Ghosal and van der Vaart](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521878268).

Answer (score -1):

[Here](http://bayesianthink.blogspot.com/2012/12/the-best-books-to-learn-probability.html) is a good collection to buy. I like the "Bundle of algorithms in Java", it gives straight out implementations/examples as does "Machine learning, practical tools and techniques" which is also a great book with practical examples. Hope that helps