# Generalizing Bayesian methods by assuming a "distribution of distributions" instead of a prior

Tags: distributions, bayesian, references, inference, asymptotics

Bayesian methods assume a prior distribution with several hyperparameters. Unfortunately, this is asymptotically incorrect, because distributions in the real world are never exact. For example, the output of flipping a coin doesn't have a Bernoulli distribution, because it may stand on its side; the measured weight distribution of people within a certain can't be normal, because numbers from a normal distribution are "almost surely" irrational.

I propose to assume a distribution of distributions instead of a prior distribution, and then to update the distribution of distributions with sample data as usual. This is a generalized Bayesian method since I'm essentially using $\aleph$ hyperparameters. I suppose doing so would result in an asymptotically correct inference method.

However, applying this method is nontrivial for me. I can't even figure out what should a "distribution of distributions" look like, and updating this distribution is presumably harder. Is there any prior work on this or a similar method?

Comment: This is called Bayesian non-parametrics.

Comment: [Nonparametric Bayes on this site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=nonparam*+baye*+answers%3A1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called nonparametric bayes, see [nonparametric-bayes](/questions/tagged/nonparametric-bayes). For a gentle introduction, see the text [Bayesian Nonparametric Data Analysis (Springer Series in Statistics)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3319189670).

A similar question was [Books for learning non parametric Bayesian model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/103997/books-for-learning-non-parametric-bayesian-model).